# JQuery click events that fire multiple times

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

my code shows a table with input checkbox, here is my problem is aue I have to check or uncheck each line and send by ajax the code, check, and libelle. When I try with an event on click the result is multiplied

```js
$(document).on('click', '.droit_data', function () {
    var id_code = $(this).attr("id");
    $.ajax({
        url: "droit.php",
        method: "post",
        data: { id_code: id_code },
        datatype: "json",
        success: function (data) {
            var html = '';
            $.each(data, function (key, value) {
                html += '<tr>';
                html += '<td><div class="form-check"><input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input droit"  name="' + data[key].libelle + '" ';
                if (data[key].droit == 'true') {
                    html += 'checked id="droit"><label class="form-check-label" for="droit">' + data[key].libelle + '</label></td>';
                } else {
                    html += 'id="droit"><label class="form-check-label" for="droit">' + data[key].libelle + '</label></td></div></tr>';
                }

            });
            $("#tab").html(html);
            $('#modelId').modal("show");

        }
    });

    $(document).on('click', '.droit', function () {
        var check = $(this).prop('checked');
        var libel = $(this).attr('name');
        $.ajax({
            url: "droit_save.php",
            method: "post",
            data: { check: check, id_code: id_code, libel: libel },
            success: function (data) {
                alert(data);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If `.droit_data` is clicked multiple times, it would register the `.droit` click multiple times. Try moving the `.droit` event registration outside the scope of the `.droit_data` event handler.

Note `id_code` will fall out of scope of the `.droit` click so I've embedded it as a data attribute on the checkbox, but you can do it however you wish.

```js
$(document).on('click', '.droit_data', function () {
    var id_code = $(this).attr("id");
    $.ajax({
        url: "droit.php",
        method: "post",
        data: { id_code: id_code },
        datatype: "json",
        success: function (data) {
            var html = '';
            $.each(data, function (key, value) {
                html += '<tr>';
                html += '<td><div class="form-check"><input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input droit"  name="' + data[key].libelle + '" ';
                if (data[key].droit == 'true') {
                    html += 'checked id="droit" data-id_code="' + id_code + '"><label class="form-check-label" for="droit">' + data[key].libelle + '</label></td>';
                } else {
                    html += 'id="droit" data-id_code="' + id_code + '"><label class="form-check-label" for="droit">' + data[key].libelle + '</label></td></div></tr>';
                }
            });
            $("#tab").html(html);
            $('#modelId').modal("show");

        }
    });
});

$(document).on('click', '.droit', function () {
    var check = $(this).prop('checked');
    var libel = $(this).attr('name');
    var id_code = $(this).data('id_code');

    $.ajax({
        url: "droit_save.php",
        method: "post",
        data: { check: check, id_code: id_code, libel: libel },
        success: function (data) {
            alert(data);
        }
    });
});
```

Edit: Added code snippet. I've replace ajax calls.

```js
$(document).on('click', '.droit_data', function () {
    var id_code = $(this).attr("id");

    var data = [
        { "droit": "true", "libelle": "test1" },
        { "droit": "false", "libelle": "test2" },
    ];

    var html = '';
    $.each(data, function (key, value) {
        html += '<tr>';
        html += '<td><div class="form-check"><input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input droit"  name="' + data[key].libelle + '" ';
        if (data[key].droit == 'true') {
            html += 'checked id="droit" data-id_code="' + id_code + '"><label class="form-check-label" for="droit">' + data[key].libelle + '</label></td>';
        } else {
            html += 'id="droit" data-id_code="' + id_code + '"><label class="form-check-label" for="droit">' + data[key].libelle + '</label></td></div></tr>';
        }

    });
    $("#tab").html(html);
    //$('#modelId').modal("show");
});

$(document).on('click', '.droit', function () {
    var check = $(this).prop('checked');
    var libel = $(this).attr('name');
    var id_code = $(this).data('id_code');
    console.log({ check: check, id_code: id_code, libel: libel });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="droit_data" id="thesource">Button</button>

<table id="tab">
</table>
```

Comment: thank you for your answer but I have to receive the id_code of .droit_data how id="<?php echo $row["code"];?> your solution gets me id="droit" of droit

Comment: That's strange, I only capture the id of `.droit_data` so I'm not sure how you get a different id. I've added a code snippet. Take a look and let me know if that is what you were expecting. It's hard to guess what your HTML looks like, so you might have to provide that structure.